# Why is the pthread_mutex_t struct all zeros in gdb?

Tags: linux, arm, gdb, mutex, glibc

What causes pthread_mutex_t struct to be all zeros?
Core of a deadlocked ARM test application in a gdb session:

```
[Switching to thread 3 (LWP 3587)]
#0  __lll_lock_wait (futex=futex@entry=0x2105c <one_mutex>, private=0) at lowlevellock.c:46
46  lowlevellock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) f 1
#1  0xaf973818 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x2105c <one_mutex>) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:81
81  pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) p mutex
$1 = (pthread_mutex_t *) 0x2105c <one_mutex>
(gdb) p (pthread_mutex_t ) 0x2105c
$2 = {
  __data = {
    __lock = 0,
    __count = 0,
    __owner = 0,
    __kind = 0,
    __nusers = 0,
    {
      __spins = 0,
      __list = {
        __next = 0x0
      }
    }
  },
  __size = '\000' <repeats 23 times>,
  __align = 0
}
```

Comment: what do you expect to see there?

Comment: I expected to see at least __owner set to the thread id currently owning the mutex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pthread_mutex_t` is used for all mutex types and some of its members are only used for specific mutex types.

`owner` member is set for at least the following mutex types:

- `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP`
- `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP`

See [glibc implementation of `pthread_mutex_trylock`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_mutex_trylock.c;h=87e87c013a6d8151d8f8a9508174ffcbdffe81ae;hb=HEAD#l34) for full more details.

Comment: Same test application compiled for x86_64 will have the pthread_mutex_t struct populated: `(gdb) p mutex.__data
$1 = {
  __lock = 2,
  __count = 0,
  __owner = 2710,
  __nusers = 1,
  __kind = 0,
  __spins = 0,
  __elision = 0,
  __list = {
    __prev = 0x0,
    __next = 0x0
  }
}`